# Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource in Payara Micro Batch Processing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, batch-processing, payara

I have a persistence.xml that works.

But when I try to do something with Batching (Jakarta Batch), it fails with the stacktrace below.

```
[#|2023-06-01T17:54:23.626+0200|SEVERE||javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.rm|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService-managedThreadFactory-Thread-4;_TimeMillis=1685634863626;_LevelValue=1000;|RAR5029:Unexpected exception while registering component
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources.
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:418)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.rm.ResourceManagerImpl.registerResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.rm.ResourceManagerImpl.enlistResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:113)
    at fish.payara.jbatch.persistence.rdbms.JBatchJDBCPersistenceManager.getConnection(JBatchJDBCPersistenceManager.java:472)
```

And after that, I get:

```
[#|2023-06-01T17:54:23.627+0200|WARNING||javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService-managedThreadFactory-Thread-4;_TimeMillis=1685634863627;_LevelValue=900;|RAR7132: Unable to enlist the resource in transaction. Evicting resource from pool. Pool name: [ H2Pool ]|#]
```

I assume it has something to do with Batching wanting to write to the Batch Tables in de default H2POOL, whilst at the same time I am trying to write my data into my tables using the ORM configured with the persistence.xml (and another connectionpool) within the same transaction.

I assume I could either:

1. make my connection pool XA instead of JTA.
   OR
2. reconfigure batch to use my connection pool instead of h2pool (how do I do that?)
   OR
3. something else?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently just slapping an @Transactional annotation on my Writer, Processor and Reader class was not the right thing to do. It caused the problem described above.

It causes the Local transaction of the Batch job to have to deal with two datasources (the H2POOL one for Batch statistics, and my own datasource) at the same time.

What worked for me, was to put a @Transactional on the appropriate methods, and I also had to specify that I require a new transaction.

So, for example in my reader:

```
@Named("addPhotographReader")
public class Reader extends AbstractItemReader
{

    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Override
    public void open(Serializable checkpoint) throws Exception
    {
```

This causes the different datasources to have their own transactions.